# Read the audio file while it's being written in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, alsa

I am capturing audio through alsa using ffmpeg and writing it to a wav file. But as it's being written I need to send the captured audio to some 3rd party. I have tried few methods including [node-growing-file](https://github.com/felixge/node-growing-file) but not able to succeed.

Is there a way I can read the file as a stream as long as it's being written and process it as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this question was down voted. But after a lot of googling I found a NPM which does this job for you:

[Tailing Stream NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailing-stream)

It will read the audio file as long as it's being written and give you the output as stream.